# Woocommerce First And Second Order Discount Coupon

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, discount, coupon

One of my client wants that when new users comes to website then they"ll get `Rs. 500` discount. Here's the complication, the discount like that on first order he get `Rs. 250` discount after entering the coupon code and on second order he also get coupon discount of `Rs. xxxx`.

NOTE : Only one coupon used at a time.

So can you please suggest me how to do that or if any plugin available like that for first and second order discount.

Comment: Why are you capitalising the initial letter of every word in your post? This just makes your question harder to read, and may irritate some readers sufficiently that they will downvote.

Comment: @halfer I just change that, but I down vote, because off topic, unclear and too broad…

Comment: @Loic, thanks. I am broadly in favour of editing open posts that will soon be closed anyway, if I think it will have an educational effect on the OP. However in this case I did wonder whether the excessive amount of work would make it worthwhile, but nevertheless, well done for the effort.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Frontend validate new customer only coupon code
 * hook: woocommerce_after_checkout_validation
 */
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation','check_new_customer_coupon', 0);

function check_new_customer_coupon(){
    global $woocommerce;
    // you might change the firstlove to your coupon
    $new_cust_coupon_code = 'firstlove';

    $has_apply_coupon = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) {
        if($code == $new_cust_coupon_code) {
            $has_apply_coupon = true;
        }
    }

    if($has_apply_coupon) {

        if(is_user_logged_in()) {
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();

            // retrieve all orders
            $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
                    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
                    'meta_value'  => $user_id,
                    'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
                    'numberposts'=> -1
            ) );

            if(count($customer_orders) > 0) {
                $has_ordered = false;

                $statuses = array('wc-failed', 'wc-cancelled', 'wc-refunded');

                // loop thru orders, if the order is not falled into failed, cancelled or refund then it consider valid
                foreach($customer_orders as $tmp_order) {

                    $order = wc_get_order($tmp_order->ID);
                    if(!in_array($order->get_status(), $statuses)) {
                        $has_ordered = true;
                    }
                }

                // if this customer already ordered, we remove the coupon
                if($has_ordered == true) {
                    WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $new_cust_coupon_code );
                    wc_add_notice( sprintf( "Coupon code: %s is only applicable for new customer." , $new_cust_coupon_code), 'error' );
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // customer has no order, so valid to use this coupon
                return true;
            }

        } else {
            // new user is valid
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

May help you. Got from some [blog](http://www.techiecorner.com/3421/woocommerce-coupon-for-new-customer-first-order-only/).

Comment: Sorry, but you have copied the code from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096816/how-do-i-programmatically-apply-a-coupon-in-woocommerce-for-first-order-made-by - Kindly:1) This code doesn't work. 2) When you answer you have to give some explanations. 3) If you have picked some code, include the links and references. So please avoid this because is not useful for the OP and for the community.

Comment: No , its got from one blog. il check and and the link

Comment: Little modification for this code may help  to set it for second order also

Comment: This is your link: http://www.techiecorner.com/3421/woocommerce-coupon-for-new-customer-first-order-only/ so please include this 2 links updating your answer… And some explanations too. If you haven't tested this code mark it as untested in your answer too…

Comment: Thanks Mujeebu. Its working fine for new customer first order but how can i ijmplement for 2nd order also.

Comment: you can apply if customer order count <= 2  , change the condition and apply :)

Comment: As per your suggestion i make the same but the second coupon is also worked for first user. i wants that the second coupon only worked for second time order. so can u please suggest me through code.

Comment: if(count($customer_orders) >= 2) {
                $has_ordered = false;
i put that code but the second order coupon is working on first time order. how can i stop it.
Conclusion : on 1st order 1st coupon is working only
                    :On 2nd order only 2nd coupon must have to worked.